# Android recyclerview - call method / function from second adapter (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm using two adapters for the same list but each is differently sorted.

This is the `adapterONE` (I removed almost everything non necessary for this question):

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val video = videolist[position]

    holder.title.text = video.id.toString()

    holder.title.setOnClickListener {
        hide(video.id)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount() = videolist.size

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.videoview, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!){
    val title = itemView!!.videoviewTitle!!
}


fun hide(id: Int){

    var ppp = 0

    for (i in 0 until videolist.size) {

        if(videolist[i].id == id){
            ppp = i
            break
        }
    }

    videolist.removeAt(ppp)
    notifyItemRemoved(ppp)
}
```

Now afer calling the `hide` function I want the same item to be removed in the second adapter so I tried:

```
videolist.removeAt(ppp)
notifyItemRemoved(ppp)
MainActivity().adapterTWO.hide(id) // this is what I added
```

And get the error:

```
lateinit property adapterTWO has not been initialized
```

But this isn't true because `adapterTWO` has loaded the content

Please help and thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

This is how I create the adapters in MainActivity

```
lateinit var adapter: RecentAdapter
lateinit var adapterTrending: TrendingAdapter

fun loadVids(endvids: MutableList<Videos>){

    adapter = RecentAdapter(this@MainActivity, endvids, isfavorites)

    recyclerViewRecent.adapter = adapter

    recyclerViewRecent.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
    recyclerViewRecent.setHasFixedSize(true)

}


fun loadVidsRecent(endvids: MutableList<Videos>){

    adapterTrending = TrendingAdapter(this@MainActivity, endvids, isfavorites)

    recyclerViewTrending.adapter = adapterTrending

    recyclerViewTrending.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
    recyclerViewTrending.setHasFixedSize(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're unwillingly creating new MainActivity (in the added code you're calling its constructor). 
It'd also help if you posted some of MainActivity code

Comment: oooh I get it. I updated the question with the important parts of MainActivity

Comment: It'll help if you posted more of MainActivity, I mean include these `adapterTWO` so we can see how instantiate them. Also, I don't quite get why you are you creating new MainActivity here `MainActivity().adapterTWO.hide(id)`

Comment: MainActivity().adapterTWO.hide(id) is what I've tried before you said why it won't work. adapterONE and adapterTWO was just to make it more clear what I want. adapterONE is actualy adapter and adapterTWO is adapterTrending