# Call Activity method from RecyclerView Adapter using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to call the

```
fun androidisgarbage(){

}
```

method which is in MainActivity from RecyclerView adapter so I try:

```
(getActivity() as MainActivity).androidisgarbage()
```

And get this error on getActivity:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun getActivity(context: Context!, requestCode: Int, intent: Intent!, flags: Int): PendingIntent! defined in android.app.PendingIntent
public open fun getActivity(context: Context!, requestCode: Int, @RecentlyNonNull intent: Intent!, flags: Int, @RecentlyNullable options: Bundle!): PendingIntent! defined in android.app.PendingIntent
```

Using context which is passed from MainActivity like so:

```
(getActivity(context) as MainActivity).androidisgarbage()
```

also isn't working

Please help!

Comment: use an interface to start event from adapter vs. or use eventbus

Comment: Please show me how to use an interface

Comment: Can you show adapter code where you call activity method?

Comment: @Tommy yeah you can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54847334/android-recyclerview-call-method-function-from-second-adapter-kotlin this is basically where all the trouble started

Answer (score 3):

In activity

```
public interface OnClickListener {
    fun onClick()
}

val adapater = Adapter(items, object: OnClickListener {
    androidisgarbage()
})
```

In adapter,

```
class Adapater (val items: List<Any>, val listener: OnClickListener) : RV... {
...
    //call to fire event on Activity
    listener.onClick()
}
```

Comment: I get on almost every detail in this code all kind of errors

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to answer this question but it can help someone in future.
You can call activity method in adapter by adapting following technique

```
class StudentListAdapter(context: Context,list: 
ArrayList<Student?>):RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
private var mContext = context
private var mList = list

// to call activity method do following 
// StudentList is activity
(mContext as StudentList).methodName()
}
```